# How to delete azureml dataset if it already exists

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk, azuremlsdk

Created an azure ml dataset. how do I delete the dataset if it already exists?

```
#register dataset
path='path'
file_ds=Dataset.File.from_files(path=path)
file_ds=file_ds.register(workspace=ws,name="Dataset")
```

Comment: [Is there a way to delete datasets on AzureML?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/567611/is-there-a-way-to-delete-datasets-on-azureml.html), [How to Delete Data Backing a Dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/379022/how-to-delete-data-backing-a-dataset.html) and [Export or delete your Machine Learning service workspace data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-export-delete-data)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT
Like the first link you mentioned but using azureml python sdk not azureml interface https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/567611/is-there-a-way-to-delete-datasets-on-azureml.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, as of now, deleting the dataset using [AzureML Python SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/search?q=delete+datasets) is not possible via `delete.datasets()`. But it might be possible via [delete_operations.py](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/396853110f5c15463e5a531ee759446d3389d441/sdk/ml/azure-ai-ml/azure/ai/ml/_restclient/dataset_dataplane/operations/_delete_operations.py)

As suggested by [YutongTie](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/567611/is-there-a-way-to-delete-datasets-on-azureml.html), you can delete the dataset using the Azure Machine Learning Studio.

References: [How to Delete Data Backing a Dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/379022/how-to-delete-data-backing-a-dataset.html), [Export or delete your Machine Learning service workspace data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-export-delete-data) and [R interface to AzureML - delete dataset](https://rdrr.io/cran/AzureML/man/delete.datasets.html)

Comment: Is there a way to update azure ml dataset using AzureML Python SDK? or is that not possible?

Comment: [dataset_v2_operations.py](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/396853110f5c15463e5a531ee759446d3389d441/sdk/ml/azure-ai-ml/azure/ai/ml/_restclient/dataset_dataplane/aio/operations/_dataset_v2_operations.py#:~:text=async%20def%20update_dataset)

Comment: @Ecstasy - Can you give a sample of how to use the functions listed in dataset_v2_operations.py? I have installed azure-ai-ml and imported _dataset_v2_operations from that package (using from azure.ai.ml._restclient.dataset_dataplane.aio.operations import _dataset_v2_operations) , but cannot seem to run those functions correctly. I am particularly interested in delete_dataset_by_name().